# Как включить Javascript для приложений и игр в Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

У меня проблема: игры и приложения в Internet Explorer не открываются, появляется надпись:

> У вас отключен Javascript.

Нашла, как его включить, появилась другая надпись

> загрузить флэш, для его загрузки нужно установить элементы ActiveX Control.

Найти это на панели информации не получается.

Comment: Попробуйте Chrome, вместо IE. Вам понравится. :) http://www.google.com/chrome?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам нужно скачать и установить [Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/ru/flashplayer/)

Answer (score 1):

Либо вариант [@psyhitus](/users/191/psyhitus) -а, либо смените браузер например на [chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome?hl=ru)